# How to get the abstract title to runin

Tags: line-breaking, abstract

We have written a style class file and I need the abstract to be in a special format to the rest of the report. It ought to look like such:

```
Abstract - text text text...
```

But with the current configuration it looks like such:

```
Abstract - 

text text text...
```

The code we use that configures the abstract looks like such:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{
 \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
 \begin{changemargin}{10mm}{10mm}
 \noindent\em Abstract -
}{
 \end{changemargin}
}
```

I found out about the `[runin]` command but with my limited LaTeX knowledge don't know where to place it (I tried several positions but from the errors I get I doubt it's designed to work with the `\renewenvironment{abstract}` command).

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**

Here is the change margin function

```
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Force of habit...

Comment: You need to show us your definition of `changemargin`.  The one on the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=chngmargonfly) does not produce a newline with your code.

Comment: I just tried your environment but did not get a line break. With a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), in other words compilable code starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, it might be easier to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is. (Sure which document class to use here needs some thought.)

Comment: There is no way for those definitions to produce a new line after "Abstract -". Only a blank line after `\begin{abstract}` will. Please, try presenting a compilable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments your code does not produce a new line so there must be a blank line in the document.

The standard latex mechanism for producing displayed environments is to use `list` or `\trivlist` If you do this then it handles ignoring blank lines at the start and merging any space before or after the environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%definition of quote with addition of [\textbf{Abstract --- ]
\renewenvironment{abstract}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item[\textbf{Abstract ---}]\relax}
               {\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}Red yellow blue\end{abstract}


\begin{abstract}

Red yellow blue

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This helped a lot thanks! When using the code you provided, the `Abstract ---` was not aligned with the paragraph's margin. I fixed it by adding a `\hspace{10mm}` before the `Abstract ---`.